# ASP.NET Cookie Update Value Without Updating Expiration?

Tags: asp.net, cookies

Is it possible to update an ASP.NET cookies value without also having to update the expiration time?  I have found that if I try and update a Cookie without also updating the expiration, that cookie no longer exists.  I have the following code which I am try to modify.  What's the point of having an expiration, if every time the cookie value is updated, so is the expiration?

```
        HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[constantCookie];

        if (cookie == null)
            cookie = new HttpCookie(constantCookie);

        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
        cookie.Value = openClose;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
```

Comment: "What's the point of having an expiration, if every time the cookie value is updated, so is the expiration?" -- Well actually that's what you want a lot of the time.  Scenarios like "if you don't visit for a month we are going to forget about you", depend upon the fact that every time you visit the cookie is set to expire a month hence.

Comment: Very true, i would definitely agree with you on this point.

Answer (score 5):

The ASP.NET HttpCookie class can not initialize the Expires property upon reading in a cookie from an HTTP request (since the HTTP specification doesn't require the client to even send the Expiration value to the server in the first place). And if you don't set the Expires property before you set the cookie back in the HTTP Response, than it turns it into a session cookie instead of a persistent one.

If you really must keep the expiration, than you could set the initial expiration date as part of the cookie value, then when you read the cookie in, parse out the value and set the new expiration to match.

An example that doesn't include any other data so the cookie isn't really helpful -- you would have to serialize it somehow with the actual data you want to store:

```
HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[constantCookie];
DateTime expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);

if (cookie == null) {
    cookie = new HttpCookie(constantCookie);
} else {
    // cookie.Value would have to be deserialized if it had real data
    expires = DateTime.Parse(cookie.Value);  
}

cookie.Expires = expires;
// save the original expiration back to the cookie value; if you want to store
// more than just that piece of data, you would have to serialize this with the
// actual data to store
cookie.Value = expires.ToString();

HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
```

Comment: Good answer, although its not just ASP.NET that does not initialise the expiry date - generally speaking, a cookies expiry date is 'write only' and is not publicised to the web server in http requests.

Comment: For me although on the server side the cookie expires value doesn't show last set value, but the browser stores the correct value even if I just update the cookie value and not expires.

Comment: @mrbengi This post relates to cookies. You posted a new question about how DateTime parsing works. There are lots of sources to find help for that, or ask a new question via the link at the top right of the StackOverflow page. But your comment doesn't apply to this topic.

Comment: @mrbengi It works fine if the cookie value wasn't created by some other system or code invalid to start with. Besides, code examples often skip basic external/user input sanitization handling for brevity, since all code should have it, so putting it in every code example is distracting.